# Passing parameter to a Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm following the guide [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_controllers.htm). When I request the URL http://localhost:xxxxx/Employee/, I want to return . Using the code below however, this will always return a 404 code. In RouteConfig.cs, if I change `"Employee/{name}"` to `"{controller}/{name}"` this will return a blank page instead.

What am I doing wrong here? I went over the tutorial a couple of times but couldn't figure out what's different.

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace scratch {
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace scratch { 
   public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new {
                   controller = "Home",
                   action = "Index",
                   id = UrlParameter.Optional
               });

            routes.MapRoute(
               "Process",
               "Process/{action}/{id}",
               new {
                   controller = "Process",
                   action = "List",
                   id = UrlParameter.Optional
               });

            routes.MapRoute(
               "Employee",
               "Employee/{name}", 
               new {
                   controller = "Employee",
                   action = "Search",
                   name = UrlParameter.Optional
               });
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace scratch.Controllers {
    public class EmployeeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Search(string name) {
            var input = Server.HtmlEncode(name);
            return Content(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The default route should always be last inside the `RegisterRoutes` method...

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the order precedence! Fixed my issue.